# how can i plot these data from the text?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to make like [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8LYR.png) using python where the data in the text file looks like this (Each row represents the data for the day, 5 days of data are shown):

-110 -108 -95 -92 -88 -87 -85 -75 -73 -69 -67 -59 -51 -49 -47 -42 -39 -35 -36 -36 -32 -27 -29 -32
-30 -23 -34 -33 -29 -25 -16 -18 -16 -17 -16 -11  -9 -13 -14 -17 -21 -20 -16 -17 -18 -15 -11 -12
-15 -12 -12 -12 -10 -14 -16 -15 -14 -12 -10  -9  -9  -9  -5  -5  -4  -6  -4  -8 -13 -17 -18 -19
-19 -20 -21 -21 -17 -14 -11 -11  -6  -3  -1   0  -1  -4  -5  -1   0   0   3   1  -5  -5  -6  -4
-3   0   1   2   1   3   1   4  12   9   6   6   8  11  14  15  18  12   5   3   5  10  12  16

The problem is that when I run the code, the data for each day overlaps each other day.

The code is below, how can I modify it to work as expected?

```
from pylab import xlabel,ylabel,xlim,ylim,show,plot
from numpy import loadtxt

data = loadtxt("2016_1.txt",float)
x = range(1,6)
y = data[:,1]
for i in range(1,23):
    y= data[:,i+1]
    plot(x,y)
    xlim(0,6)
    ylim(-120,100)       
show()
```

This is what i get when I run it: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28QJr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the plot is called 23 times and all the times, x axis is limited to 5 units and y axis is getting overwritten and therefore 23 different plots.

The solution is to append y into a single large array and then plot that array.
See the below sample code:

```
from pylab import xlabel,ylabel,xlim,ylim,show,plot

from numpy import loadtxt

import numpy as np

data = loadtxt("2016_1.txt",float)
#x = range(1,6) ## not needed
y = data[:,1]
z = y

for i in range(1,23):
    y= data[:,i+1]
    z = np.append(z,y) ## append y to z to create an entire range of values

plot(z)
#xlim(0,6)  ## commented this to cover entire range
ylim(-120,100)       
show()
```

Comment: thank you, but how i can modify it to count row by row instead of column by column.

Comment: By default elements of z are plotted on y axis. If you want to plot them on x axis, You can use something like this:

x = range(1,116) #before the for loop.

plot(z,x) #after the for loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, God bless you.